# Snowflake Service Account for Alation

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, alation

Our organization is looking to bring on board the Alation product for data mining.

To do so, Alation requires a service account in Snowflake to touch every database, every schema in Snowflake.

Obviously this is very broad access and the org is concerned about security.

Has anyone else done this, and possibly quantify the risks involved?

Comment: This is pretty typical of data governance tools. In order to get a full view of what's in your databases, they need access to them. There should be a security layer inside Alation that would limit what people can see inside it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is overly-broad for the Q/A format of StackOverflow. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. It's not really possible for someone unfamiliar with your specific case to quantify the risks associated with giving another service access to your data. Can you rephrase the question in a way that it can have a "correct answer?"